# Use RegEx and wildcard search to find a pattern

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, regex

I want to find a pattern in a document that looks like:

> 1234567 Ver:3

The numbers will change, but the structure will remain the same. I want to find that value, and assign the following text to a variable which will be used to name the document:

> 1234567-3.

Here is what I have and was working when the document had the pattern:

> 1234567-3

Now the document displays that information as

> 1234567 Ver:3.

Can you help me using the find function and transforming to the new format?

```
Sub FindPattern()
Dim regEx As Object
Dim matchCollection As Object
Dim eString As String
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regEx
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Global = False    ' Only look for 1 match; False is actually the default.
  .Pattern = "[0-9]{7} - [0-9]{1}"  ' Word separates lines with CR (\r)
End With
```

There are three requirements:

- Pass the text of your document as the text to search through to regEx.Execute().
- For a quick test of this statement, pass "Program: Program Name (abr)"
  Set matchCollection = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
- Extract the first submatch's (capture group's) value -
  E.g. "Program Name (abr)" - and assign it to variable `extractedString`.
  This line used to have `estring = matchCollection(0).Submatch(0)` to extract the first match, but I was getting errors.
  This is my code:

  ```
  eString = matchCollection(0)
  '
  On Error Resume Next
  '
  Dim strName As String, dlgSave As Dialog
  Set dlgSave = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)

  ' name with date and quote number
  strName = Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & "_" & _
  Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") & "_" & _
      Format((Year(Now()) Mod 100), "20##") & "_ _" & eString
  With dlgSave
      .Name = strName
      .Show
  End With
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Function FindPattern(myText As String, ByRef result As String) As Boolean
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim extract As Variant

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .Global = False
      '.Pattern = "([0-9]{7}) - ([0-9]{1})"      ' Pattern <1234567 - 3>
      .Pattern = "([0-9]{7}) Ver:([0-9]{1})"    ' Pattern <1234567 Ver:3>
    End With
    Set extract = regEx.Execute(myText)
    If extract.Count = 0 Then
        result = ""
        FindPattern = False
    Else
        ' Result a la <1234567-3>
        result = extract(0).subMatches(0) & "-" & extract(0).subMatches(1)
        FindPattern = True
    End If
End Function

Sub test_Findpattern()
    Dim theText As String
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim Sresult As String

    theText = "Blabla     1234567 - 3 blabla"
    result = FindPattern(theText, Sresult)
    Debug.Print 1, result, Sresult

    theText = "Blabla     1234567 Ver:3 blabla"
    result = FindPattern(theText, Sresult)
    Debug.Print 2, result, Sresult

    theText = Application.ActiveDocument.Range
    result = FindPattern(theText, Sresult)
    Debug.Print 3, result, Sresult

    Debug.Print "====="

End Sub
```

This should be what you need.

In the function you can comment out either of the `.pattern=` statements in order to use your old pattern or your new pattern.

The Sub `test_Findpattern()` has three sections, the last one takes all the text from your Word document.

Assuming your word document contains the new pattern, the output of the test-sub will be like:

```
 1            Falsch        
 2            Wahr          1234567-3
 3            Wahr          1234567-3
 =====
```